# Brightness controls don't work on Macbook - Stuck on high (Nvidia GeForce 9400M)

Tags: 12.10, brightness, macbook

I am using a Macbook (Aluminum Late 2008 version) and dual booting ubuntu 12.10

After installation the keyboard controls for volume and brightness worked perfectly,but a few days later the brightness got stuck on high and it's been giving me headaches and is super annoying. I can't use the keyboard controls for brightness or change it in the settings. I've tried searching for a fix but nothing has worked so far. Any suggestions?

Also i have played around with the graphics drivers and i'm currently using: NVIDIA binary Xorg driver. Should i change this?
(Go easy on me, i'm a newbie :))

Graphics: Nvidia GeForce 9400M/integrated/SSE2
OS Type: 32-bit
I'll provide any extra information needed

Comment: I tried the above on my Macbook late 2009 model and it worked! Thank you so much! I did have to do all the steps though, but it was easy, if anyone else is having this issue, then try it, it works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

♡ I found a solution! Hopefully someone finds this useful. I probably did more steps than required but here is what worked for me. ♡
(Nvidia users only)

1. Open Terminal and enter the command below to open the xorg.conf file for editing:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   ```
2. Once the file opens, find Section “Device” and add

   ```
   Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
   ```

   (as shown below in bold line), and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to save it.

In my case, this file was empty so I entered the exact text and saved it to `/etc/X11`.

```
Section "Device"
Identifier      "Default Device"
Option   "NoLogo" "True"
Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1″
EndSection
```

[Source](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/fix-laptop-brightness-toggle-issues-in-ubuntu-10-10-and-11-04-tip/)

---

After restarting, if this did not work for you I also did the following:

3. Just create a file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-nvidia.conf` with the following content:

   ```
   Section "Device"
       Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
       Identifier "Device0"
   EndSection
   ```

   Again, in my case some of these files didn't exist so I created them myself. When everything was in place I restarted and now my brightness controls are working

In order to create them manually open terminal and enter:

```
gksu nautilus
```

From there on navigate to: `/etc/X11/` and create a folder named   `xorg.conf.d`. Then inside that folder create a file named   `50-nvidia.conf` using gedit with the content listed in the step 3.

Now restart your computer.

[Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/1006453/)

Comment: Just to note, the first solution here worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 on an iMac9,1 (early 2009), too. (For me, xorg.conf already existed.) Thanks!

Comment: This prevented Xorg from running on our iMac9,1 and consoles not accessible either.  Lucky we could delete the files over ssh.